# Multiply value in SQL script

Tags: mysql

How can i multiply value in SQL only for in my case specific device (IP)?

My table:

| ID | DEVICE | POWER | ENERGY | DATE_OF_READING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 192.168.25.35 | 165 | 250241 | 2023-09-15 08:25:04 |
| 2 | 192.168.25.36 | 320 | 190322 | 2023-09-15 08:25:04 |

What i want is that sql will return value **650** = 165 x 2 + 320

Currently my script looks like this

```
SELECT SUM(power) AS "POWER", CONVERT_TZ(date_of_reading,'+2:00','+00:00') AS "DATE OF READING" 
FROM energy.realtime 
WHERE device IN ('192.168.25.35', '192.168.25.36')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To multiply the `POWER` value by `2` for a specific device (IP) in your SQL query, you can use a `CASE` statement within the `SUM` function.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN device = '192.168.25.35' THEN power * 2 ELSE power END) AS "POWER", 
    CONVERT_TZ(date_of_reading,'+2:00','+00:00') AS "DATE OF READING" 
FROM energy.realtime 
WHERE device IN ('192.168.25.35', '192.168.25.36')
```

Comment: Thank you for you help !! working as i wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with this querie:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(device='192.168.25.35',power*2,power)) AS "POWER"
 ,CONVERT_TZ(date_of_reading,'+2:00','+00:00') AS "DATE OF READING" 
FROM energy.realtime 
WHERE device IN ('192.168.25.35', '192.168.25.36');
```